# Is it possible to update a website element based upon another website?

Tags: php, html

I am going to provide an example to make my question more understandable. There is a website 
which utilizes PHP, and on this website the objective is to create an element, such as an 
image in this instance, and update the source of this image with respect to an image source of 
another website. This way this image will always be identical to that of the image it is obtaining its source from. The concept here is to keep one site up to date automatically, 
rather than having to go in and update the source manually.

Comment: Are both website domains managed by you? Do you have,the legal ownership of both website back end front end?

Comment: One website I do have complete ownership back-end and front-end, the other however is a Wordpress website. I have ownership of this, front-end, but I am not sure of the legal conditions of Wordpress and back-hand usage. Most likely they will allow to do this, I will check however before implementing this.

Comment: If you have the ownership of the source site, the content is yours and you can do whatever you want with it. You don't need Wordpress's authorization.

Comment: are the two sites going to show the same image?

Comment: Well if the image is on another site, can't you just use: `<img src="http://www.othersitethatbelongstoyou.com/image.png" />`?

Comment: The problem with this however would be that this source pertains that ONE image, I need the most recent image.

Comment: Then create a page that just has <?php header("location: the URL of the most recent image"); ?> and reference that page as the src in an <img /> tag

Comment: Right, but then how can I make this source update automatically, so that is relative to the most recent image?

Comment: it's not really an update. when the page is requested it gets the source of the most recent image, every time.

Comment: I've updated my answer now we know the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use file_get_contents() + regular expression to achieve that. But it would be better if the source website just give you this information (by providing a JSON or a XML with the necessary information you want).

Comment: Which of these methods is more practical?

Comment: The second. It's easier, cleaner and more certain of working.

Comment: What if you use first strategy but word press keeps on changing their front end data. You have to be like God then with continues TRACKING... If you come to conditions with word press where you get JASON or XML file, they consider you/track you. See the difference?

Comment: In the instance I am using it, I will always be taking the most recent data from the most recent post. Is their a way to to make sure that the data be transfered is through the most recent, rather than the same file.

Comment: Yes. You just have to fetch the last entry in your Wordpress and then get the info you want of it, convert to JSON (or XML) and provide it to the other website.

Comment: @bonCodigo Exactly. As I said, Regex would work but it isn't the better approach.

Comment: ;-)  I am not against you. was speaking to OP

Comment: And I am agreeing with you. hahahah Actually, it's good teach people the practical differences between different approaches. +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

Ok now we know what the real question is, create a new page template in your wordpress theme

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Most Recent Thumbnail
*/
?>

<?php
$rs = new WP_Query();
$rs->query('showposts=20');
while ($rs->have_posts()) : $rs->the_post();

    if (has_post_thumbnail()) 
    {
        header('location:/'.get_bloginfo('url').wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ));
        die;
    }
endwhile; 

//if we got here no image was found in the last 20 posts, we should send the page to a backup image 
header('location: http://some.image');
die;
```

Create a new page in the management area, select the template Most Recent Thumbnail, give it a title of Most Recent Thumbnail and publish it.

```
<img src="http://mywordpress.site/most-recent-thumbnail" />
```